# How to share templates between java servlets packed to a separate WAR's?

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, freemarker

I have **Freemarker template** and I wish to **share** it between my Java Servlets packed to a **separate** WAR's.

What is the **correct** place for such a **common** templates?
I use Apache Tomcat 7 and I don't want to put all of them to `/var/lib/tomcat7`

This question is **NOT** about how to share application code and where to put JAR files or how to use `extends` in Java. It is even **NOT** about how to share web.xml.

The question is how to share **common templates** and where is a right place for shared templates.

Comment: Anywhere you want in the war file. Have you read http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html?

Comment: Are you using multiple servlets within one WAR or do you have multiple WARs?

Comment: @fabian I am using several servlets packed to a separate WAR files.

Comment: @JBNizet It would be better to publish templates separately.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on why is this needed. One possibility is putting the templates into a Maven artifact that both war-s depend on (possibly transitively). Then you can use `ClassTemplateLoader` to access them. Another possibility is having an application home directory somewhere, like `/var/lib/myapp`, and then have a `templates` subdirectory in it (and later maybe some others for other shared application data). The application home directory should be specified with an environment variable or Java System property, so it can be decided by those who install the application, and the application can read what it is. Then in the war-s you could use `FileTemplateLoader` to load the templates.